# Why this site is not allowing to us to comment?

Tags: discussion

When I tried to comment to a question I was told "you can't comment  because  your reputation is below 50" and I want to know why they are saying that.

Comment: "because your reputation is below 50"

Comment: I know it! its okay

Comment: The canonical question is *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)* (cross site, part of the Stack Exchange FAQ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put simply, if everyone who signed up was able to comment immediately, all the Stack Exchange sites would fill up with spam overnight.  I don't think anybody really wants this.

Answer (score 8):

In all seriousness the is no vetting for accounts other than on-site mechanics.

Like a lot of other restrictions this is to limit the amount of damage a malicious actor can do without investing a lot more time and energy than most people will consider worth the pay-off.